# DeGroot P.155 integration problem for multivariate distributions

Tags: mathematical-statistics, integral, multivariate-distribution

I am stuck with the integral for equation 3.7.4 and do not see how it was done. Could someone provide me with some hints or resources to read around?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the property that $\int \frac{1}{x^p} dx = -\frac{1}{p-1}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}$

Let $(2+x_1+ \cdots+x_{n-1}) = d$ (some constant) wrt $x_n$
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{c}{\left(2+x_{1}+\cdots+x_{n}\right)^{n+1}} d x_{n}= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{c}{\left(d +x_{n}\right)^{n+1}} d x_{n}  = \frac{\frac{c}{n} }{(d+x_n)^n} |_{0}^{\infty}\\= \frac{c / n}{\left(2+x_{1}+\cdots+x_{n-1}\right)^{n}}
$$

Comment: The second to last entry should be negative right? $-\frac{\frac{c}{n} }{(d+x_n)^n}$ because shouldn't the initial property be $\int \frac{1}{x^p} dx = \frac{1}{1-p}\frac{1}{x^{1-p}}$???

Comment: @Investing A negative sign was missing in the first line.  I have inserted one there.

Comment: Perfect, thank you